# How can I use a loop to create a comma delimited value without an extra comma at the end?

Tags: css, sass

I'm using @for to create multiple box-shadow arguments:

```
.myclass {

    $bxsw : "";
    @for $i from 1 through 10 {
      $bxsw : $bxsw + " -" + $i + "px -" + $i + "px " + brown + ",";
    }

    box-shadow: #{$bxsw};

}
```

Which gives me:

```
.myclass {
    box-shadow: -1px -1px brown, -2px -2px brown, -3px -3px brown, -4px -4px brown, -5px -5px brown, -6px -6px brown, -7px -7px brown, -8px -8px brown, -9px -9px brown, -10px -10px brown,;
}
```

Notice that last extra comma? This causes Firefox not to render the box-shadows. Is there a programmatic way of removing the last comma?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest method is to append to a comma delimited list.

```
.myclass {
    $bxsw : ();
    @for $i from 1 through 10 {
      $bxsw : append($bxsw, $i * -1px $i * -1px brown, comma);
    }

    box-shadow: $bxsw;
}
```

http://sassmeister.com/gist/7b8221953c7ca9813aea

Comment: This is indeed the simplest method, thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Method #1:** One option is to set a base value for `$bxsw`, then iterate the loop from `2`:

```css
.myclass {
    $bxsw : "-1px -1px brown";
    @for $i from 2 through 10 {
      $bxsw : $bxsw + ", -" + $i + "px -" + $i + "px " + brown;
    }

    box-shadow: #{$bxsw};
}
```

**Method #2:** Another option would be checking if the `$bxsw` is not empty in order to append the comma:

```css
.myclass {
    $bxsw : "";
    @for $i from 1 through 10 {
      @if ($bxsw != "") { $bxsw: $bxsw + ", "; }
      $bxsw : $bxsw + "-" + $i + "px -" + $i + "px " + brown;
    }

    box-shadow: #{$bxsw};
}
```

**Method #3:** And also we can check if the current iteration number is the last one or not:

```css
.myclass {
    $bxsw: ""; $from: 1; $to: 10;

    @for $i from $from through $to {
      $bxsw : $bxsw + "-" + $i + "px -" + $i + "px " + brown;
      @if ($i < $to) { $bxsw: $bxsw + ", "; }
    }

    box-shadow: #{$bxsw};
}
```

Comment: great answers, I'm going to go with cimmanon's answer since I used that one. But I really appreciate you putting the time to explain the different methods, I learned a lot from your responses. Thank you very much.